# Why String get converted to Long even when the parameter is String when querying

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "product_wallet")
@NamedQuery(name = "ProductWallet.findAll", query = "SELECT pw FROM ProductWallet pw")
@EntityListeners(CUEntityListener.class)
public class ProductWallet implements Serializable, CUEntity {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "product_wallet_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
  private Long productWalletId;

  @Column
  private Integer total;

  @Column
  private String status;

  @Column(name = "user_id", updatable = false, insertable = false)
  private String userId;

  @Column(name = "member_id", updatable = false, insertable = false)
  private Long memberId;

  @Column(name = "provider_id", updatable = false, insertable = false)
  private String providerId;

  @Column(name = "created_by", length = 100)
  private String createdBy;

  @Column(name = "created_date")
  private Timestamp createdDate;

  @Column(name = "modified_by", length = 50)
  private String modifiedBy;

  @Column(name = "modified_date")
  private Timestamp modifiedDate;

  //bi-directional many-to-one association to MUser
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id")
  private MUser user;

  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "member_id")
  private Member member;

  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "provider_id")
  private Provider provider;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "productWallet")
  private List<ProductWalletItem> productWalletItems;
```

I am trying to use this method using the automatic query creation by JPA, writing the query manually, etc.

```
ProductWallet findProductWalletByProviderIdAndMemberId(String providerId, Long memberId);
```

but for some reason, String providerId get converted to Long for all of them and I get this error. It seems like jdbc is desperately trying to convert something to Long:

```
Bad value for type long : PR_0000000288
2019-10-11 19:12:56 - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute query; SQL [select productwal0_.product_wallet_id as product_1_41_, productwal0_.created_by as created_2_41_, productwal0_.created_date as created_3_41_, productwal0_.member_id as member_i4_41_, productwal0_.modified_by as modified5_41_, productwal0_.modified_date as modified6_41_, productwal0_.provider_id as provider7_41_, productwal0_.status as status8_41_, productwal0_.total as total9_41_, productwal0_.user_id as user_id10_41_ from product_wallet productwal0_ where productwal0_.provider_id=? and productwal0_.member_id=?]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute query] with root cause
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Bad value for type long : PR_0000000288
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.toLong(PgResultSet.java:2860)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.getLong(PgResultSet.java:2114)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.getLong(PgResultSet.java:2506)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.proxy.HikariResultSetProxy.getLong(HikariResultSetProxy.java)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BigIntTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(BigIntTypeDescriptor.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47)
```

Comment: Do you have access to database? It seems there is a "PR_0000000288" in your table?

Comment: @aksappy I do have access to the DB and provider_id is "PR_0000000288" and that column datatype is varchar(100)

Comment: What is the Id for Member class?

Comment: @aksappy memberId for this row is 18468 which is bigInt. I run the query in the DB it works fine but not with jpa

Comment: Kindly share the Provider entity class too as it looks like you have the Id field in the Provider class as Long and the ProductWallet has a providerId as String. Hence the former is taken in the query and so the error.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's because you have two `provider_id` column in your table. One for the filed `providerId` and the other for the join column for `Provider` object. I assume the id for the object `Provider` is Long type. Can you rename one of these and try?